# File exchange API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, streaming, peer

Does anyone know if there is an API for file exchange out there?

The main goal is to build a web application that provides an opportunity to ***attach files to groups***, like vk.com(Social net), using an external file exchange service. The goal is to *PULL* a file in so that other users can go and *GET* it.

Comment: Maybe Dropbox could do the trick

Comment: @apneadiving You saved me twice a day! How could i forget about DropBox. I`ll give it a try tomorrow evening! But maybe there are some more opportunities?

Comment: Next time tell me to post my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox currently provides an API (and also a Ruby library to interact with this API) here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases

Comment: Do you really suggest as an answer the comment I posted hours ago?

Comment: Yepp! @mayoral I`ve looked it up! Pretty nice... @apneadiving Pretty same decision.